# formulario logueo con composite control

Tags: c#, formularios, aplicación-escritorio

Tengo este formulario de logueo creado con composite control pero me tira error de cadena de entrada, ¿qué sería ese error?

```
        private void btnIniciarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                int cedula=0;
                string contraseña="";
                try
                {
                    cedula = Convert.ToInt32(_Logueo.Usuario);
                }
                catch
                {
                    lblerror.Text = "Cedula Incorrecta";
                }
                contraseña = _Logueo.Contraseña;
                ILogicaEmpleado LEmpleado = FabricaLogica.getLogicaEmpleado();
                Empleado _unEmpleado = LEmpleado.BuscarEmpleadoLogueo(cedula, contraseña);

                if (_unEmpleado == null)
                {
                    lblerror.Text = "No existe el Empleado";

                }
                else
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    //pasarcedula(_Login.Usuario);
                    FrmDefault _unfrm = new FrmDefault();
                    _unfrm.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblerror.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: en que lugar tira ese error?

Comment: el error esta en la operacion donde pongo los datos, que se encuentra en el control , ejecutando el frmlogueo , cargo los datos , click en iniciar sesion y al instante da el error, es como que no toma los datos ( cedula , contrasenia) en el mismo campo dentro del try de cedula, ya te expulsa de la depuracion

Comment: y en que linea da.. y podes mostrar el codigo que genera el error? y todo el mensaje de error? si no va a ser dificil ayudarte